# How can I call Timer as a method?

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
package com.example.wackamole;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static int scoreCount;
static Timer t;
static int count;
static int timeInterval;   

    protected TextView textView, counter;
    protected ImageButton button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t = new Timer();

    scoreCount = 0;
    count = 0;
    timeInterval = 1000;

   button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mole);
   button.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
   textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);

   t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (count%2 == 0)
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.mole);
                else
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.hole);

                count++;
                textView.setText("Score:" + count);


            }

        });

    }
},0, timeInterval);

    findViewById(R.id.mole).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View v){


                if (timeInterval > 100)
                    timeInterval -= 50;


                if (t != null){
                    t.cancel();
                    t.purge();
                    t = null;
                }
            }
            });

    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I want to be able to stop the timer when I click the button, and then restart the timer again (this time, the timer interval is smaller so it will be faster). Is it something like onCreate()? or onResume? and if so, can someone explain those to me?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Could you make your question clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you right, you are trying to create a single timer, that will be canceled and reset upon pushing a button. If so, i think this should work for you.

Outside of your onCreate you could create a method that handles the cancel and creation of the timer:

```
private void setupTimer() {
    t.cancel();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (count % 2 == 0)
                        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.mole);
                    else
                        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.hole);

                    count++;
                    textView.setText("Score:" + count);
                }
            });
        }
    }, timeInterval);
}
```

Timer.schedule() seemed to fit your needs. You can read more about the different methods that Timer offers at: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate() continuously fires at a given interval. The rate of the interval is fixed and won't suit your needs to reduce the timer interval each button press.

Now inside your onCreate you can call this new method when a user clicks your button:

```
    findViewById(R.id.mole).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (timeInterval > 100)
                timeInterval -= 50;

            setupTimer();
    }
});
```

S